# How do I find out why something is in /mnt?

Tags: filesystems

I have an unexpected entry in /mnt (called test) which I am sure is a left over from when I was experimenting a while ago, but I cannot remember why it was done, or why it is still being mounted. Is there a way to find out what script has caused that directory to be mounted so that I can remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find out what mounted it, but you can see if it's still mounted by looking at the output of `mount` or even just attempting to remove the mountpoint, `rmdir /mnt/test` (success means nothing was mounted there).

To unmount a filesystem mounted there, `umount /mnt/test` and then `rmdir /mnt/test`

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in your `~/.bash_history` (or the appropriate history file, if present).

Otherwise, the `mount` command with no parameters will tell you whether the directory is indeed mounted (also check `/etc/fstab` just in case).

You might also try looking (using `find`) in the whole system for files changed or created more or less at the same time as your `/mnt/test`.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, `/mnt` is a directory like any other. You can create files and directories under it, not just `mount(8)` stuff there. Also note that if you have, say, `/mnt/test` and go `mount /dev/whatever /mnt`, while `whatever` is mounted there, `/mnt/test` is totally unacessible. If you reboot, presumably nothing gets mounted there and `/mnt/test` will be sitting there.